# SetProperty vs DOM style Property in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm confused by those property blow , why DOM style Property not working in IE 11?

```js
arrow.style = 'visibility:hidden'; // not working
arrow.setAttribute = ('style','visibility:visible'); // works fine.
arrow.style.setProperty('visibility', 'visible'); // works fine.
```

Comment: here : `arrow.style.visibility = "hidden"`

Comment: From MDN: *"Styles should not be set by assigning a string directly to the style property (as in `elt.style = "color: blue;"`), since it is considered read-only, as the style attribute returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object which is also read-only. Instead, styles can be set by assigning values to the properties of style."*

Comment: *"For adding specific styles to an element without altering other style values, it is preferred to use the individual properties of style (as in `elt.style.color = '...'`) as using `elt.style.cssText = '...'` or `elt.setAttribute('style', '...')` sets the complete inline style for the element by overriding the existing inline styles. "* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style

Comment: According to the CSS spec (https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-elementcssinlinestyle-mixin) it should work, but who knows. Assigning to `cssText` is the safer option I guess.

Comment: thanks, I’ve got it !!

Comment: From the last comment, it seems that you have got the answer. I suggest @FelixKling to put his comments as an answer so that you can mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the CSSOM spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-elementcssinlinestyle-mixin), this should work, but it's also only a draft and it may not be consistent across browsers.

Anyway, the spec says that assigning to the `style` property should be treated the same as assigning directly to `style.cssText`. So I would do just that instead.

Also from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style):

> Styles should not be set by assigning a string directly to the style property (as in `elt.style = "color: blue;"`), since it is considered read-only, as the style attribute returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object which is also read-only. Instead, styles can be set by assigning values to the properties of style. For adding specific styles to an element without altering other style values, it is preferred to use the individual properties of style (as in `elt.style.color = '...'`) as using `elt.style.cssText = '...'` or `elt.setAttribute('style', '...')` sets the complete inline style for the element by overriding the existing inline styles.

Comment: Could link where it's being written that "assigning to the style property should be treated the same as assigning directly to style.cssText." I can't find it in the link you provided. Also, this should always have worked because `.style` is an IDL attribute which at setting should set the attribute's value, but it's more on [the HTML side](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-style-attribute): "the attribute's value must be parsed when the attribute is added or has its value changed,"

Comment: @Kaiido: That's what the `PutForwards=cssText` extended attribute means. https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#PutForwards *"the attribute's value must be parsed when the attribute is added or has its value changed"* From my understanding that applies to `element.setAttribute("style", ....)`, not necessarily to assigning to the `style` *property*.

Comment: Never saw that PutForward webidl attribute before, quite a complicated one.